# Firebase 3.0 Android Locale Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, locale, firebase-authentication

In the new version of Firebase, how to catch the user's Locale connected on Facebook that was previously in ProviderData of AuthData?

CODE OLD VERSION:

```
private class AuthResultHandler implements Firebase.AuthResultHandler {

.......

@Override
public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
       mapa = (HashMap<String,String>)  authData.getProviderData().get("cachedUserProfile");
       paisSigla = mapa.get("locale").split("_",2)[1];
       paisesArray = Constantes.PAISES;
       paisesMap = new HashMap<String, String>(paisesArray.length);
       for (int index = 0; index < paisesArray.length; index++) {
           paisesMap.put(paisesArray[index][0], paisesArray[index][1]);
       }
       paisExtenso = paisesMap.get(paisSigla);
       paisPesquisa = paisesMap.get(paisSigla).toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
       provedor = (String) authData.getProvider();
       if(provedor.equals("facebook")){
           consultarUsuario(FBASE + paisPesquisa + ....);
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you used to do this with the previous Firebase SDK? Because I'm not sure how this specific case used to work.

Comment: Frank, Add the code in the previous version to become more clear. In my app I need to know the user country to customize and internationalize the interface.

Comment: Frank, In the previous version of the Firebase brought the country's public_profile of Facebook in ProviderData.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're looking for. That cached user profile does not exist on the 3.x SDK at the moment. We're looking to add some of that information back in the future, but I'm not sure when or what exactly. For the moment, you will have to get the information directly from the Facebook SDK after the user is signed in. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase

Comment: So, you're forcing me to do twice the same operation on Facebook. First, the Firebase, on behalf of my app, connected and picked up some data. Then I connect again to get additional data. In the previous SDK had an object (CachedProfile - of ProviderData) that brought all the data public profile (Locale inclusive). It was enough to continue bringing the complete object - as before. It makes life easier. Since Firebase took X, take X + Y;